# Combine database queries

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

ID    / x_id / x_key  / x_value

---

322  / 4     / name  / Jack

323  / 5     / name  / Mary

324  / 6     / name  / John

325  / 4     / hide    / 1

326  / 5     / hide    / 0

327  / 6     / hide    / 0

---

I would like to select the names from the persons which "hide" key corresponds to the "0" value.
Here these selected "x_values" would then be **Mary and John**

To do so, I have the x_id that I can compare between records.

Which x_id's correspond to an x_ key="hide" that matches an x_value = "0"?

Both x_id's 5 and 6.

Which "x_values" are corresponding to these two x_id's where the x_key="name"? Mary and John

In other words, I try to get a single query that would mix these two queries in order to get Mary and John only:

**Query A:**

```
SELECT 
    x_id,
    x_value 
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    x_key='name'
```

**Query B:**

```
SELECT 
    x_id 
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    x_key='hide' 
AND 
    x_value='0'
```

I just don't find the correct way to do that.
How can I?

I'm really sorry for the explanation but I'm not english and it is very hard to explain.

Comment: What is your table stucture?

Comment: id - x_id - x_key - x_value.
Thank you

Comment: `x_id is a foreign key` ... to which table?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood you correct you want to select the elements that have a specific `x_key` with `x_value = '0'` and that are not hidden (`x_key != 'hide'`).

EDIT (according to your edit):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f46ac8/1)

```
SELECT bb.x_value
FROM mytable AS aa
INNER JOIN mytable AS bb
ON aa.x_id = bb.x_id
WHERE aa.x_key = 'hide' AND aa.x_value = 0 AND bb.x_key = 'name';
```

OLD ANSWER (before your edit):

```
SELECT x_id, x_key, x_value
FROM mytable
WHERE x_key='name' AND x_key != 'hide' AND x_value = '0'
```

Comment: If you mean something different then please update your question accordingly giving more information.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope this time it will be clearer. I really do my best.

Answer (score 1):

You should use join to connect two instances of the table - one for the names and one for the 'hides'

```
select n.x_id, n.x_value from mytable as h inner join myable as n on 
h.x_id = n.x_id where n.x_key = 'name' and h.x_key = 'hide' and H.x_value = 0;
```

while this will work, I think it's not a good practice to have two types of data in the same table. I'd recommend you to split it to two tables- one for names and one for hides

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to retrieve data from this table, I'm not the one who created it. In fact, this is the Wordpress postmeta table...
It's a generic table that plugins creators can take advantage o without messing with the database. It's not ideal but it allows to insert almost everything (key=> value) without the need to change the table structure itself. I'll try your query and will get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want combine 2 'SELECT' with different 'WHERE' statments. You can use 'OR' statment

```
SELECT x_id,x_value FROM mytable WHERE x_key='name' OR x_key='hide' AND x_value='0'
```

Comment: That's not it but thank you anyway. See the updated question if you want to know what it was all about.